# Download missing dependencies when building projects?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, compiling, source

Bit of a noob question. Sometimes there are GitHub projects that I clone into my system and then try to build using some kind of a build tool. Most of the times, the dependencies will be listed in the `README.md` page, sometimes they are not, sometimes they *are* listed but it turns out my system does not have some other package that was *not* listed, which typically happens to be some kind of a missing library. This is when I do something like

```bsh
apt search <package/library-name>
```

This typically returns *a lot* of results including ones that are already installed and I find myself piping the results to filter out the ones that are already installed :

```bsh
apt search <package/library-name> | grep -v installed
```

This narrows it down but not by much and I have to try guessing which would best work (since a lot of them have similar names) so I am definitely going about this the wrong way which is why I have to ask:

- is there a way of knowing **exactly** what dependencies are missing and what you should install?
- is there a **general** way of building files that circumvents all this hassle ?

Any resources on this issue will be of great help. Thanks !

Comment: If it is in the repositories, you can run `apt build-dep <pkgname>` to install all build dependencies. If it is in the [AUR (Arch User Repository)](https://aur.archlinux.org/), you can look at the dependencies and install them (they might have different names on Ubuntu and you might need the `-dev` version as well)